# Correct configuration of VLAN for second network

Tags: vlan, internet, video

I have a problem with setting up VLAN for correctly working internet connection through one cable. My ISP have Data and Video connection which are basically separated:

- Data is used for normal internet activities such as browsing on web and local connection between computers
- Video is used for IPTV and archived content of TV channels (timeshift)

If I connect my computer to data with one cable on one interface (eth0) the network is located on 192.168.1.0 /24. If I disconnect data cable and connect my computer to video with the same cable on same interface the network is located on 10.10.8.0 /22. In both cases there is running dhcp server and I get different DNS IPs as well. But the thing is that my ISP also provides trunk connection which split data connection to VLAN ID 0 and video connection to VLAN ID 100.

Here is some info about my network when connected only to Data port:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:192.168.1.12  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10015 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10056386 (10.0 MB)  TX bytes:32561 (32.5 KB)
```

And also for network when connected only to Video port:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:10.10.10.29  Bcast:10.10.11.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8267 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9754438 (9.7 MB)  TX bytes:14789 (14.7 KB)
```

Because I would like to access to both "types" of connection, I installed vlan package (I'm using Xubuntu 14.04) and tried to somehow connected both parts. So there is my config from `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 eth0.100

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
 mtu 1492

allow-hotplug eth0.100
iface eth0.100 inet static
 address 10.10.10.29
 netmask 255.255.252.0
 gateway 10.10.8.1
 dns-nameservers 10.240.93.5 10.240.93.6
 dns-search isp-domain.com
 vlan_raw_device eth0
 up route add -net 10.240.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth0.100
 up route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev eth0.100
```

I'm using static configuration for `eth0.100` because I can't get DHCP working for VLAN 100. Internet connection (eth0) is working without the problem and I get IP from DHCP server (192.168.1.12). The problem is with video connection (eth0.100) because I have static IP and I'm able to access multicast streams (IPTV), but I can't access to DNS (10.240.93.5 and 10.240.93.6). I need DNS because I only have links pointing to archive content (timeshift) and there are different domains which needs to be resolved. I also tried to enter IP instead of domain for content archive which I got previously when my computer was connected only to video, but the problem remains, I'm not able to watch anything from archive. If I try to lookup for IP from DNS server:

```
johnny@home:~$ nslookup
> server 10.240.93.5
Default server: 10.240.93.5
Address: 10.240.93.5#53
> nslookup archive.isp-domain.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
>
```

In the case above, `archive.isp-domain.com` is pointing to HTTP server where the content is stored. This domain is accessible only from local network 10.10.8.0 /22. If I ran the same lookup when I'm connected only to video port, I get back correct IP address which is pointing to content archive where I'm able to watch videos.

Because I know only the basics of networking and some theoretical part of VLANs, I don't know what could be wrong. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you also getting a default gateway from your native vlan "data"?  That could be part of your problem.

Comment: @Ron yes, 192.168.1.1 is set as default gateway. The problem is also that I can't ping gateway of eth0.100 from eth0.100. I don't know why...

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct default gateway on eth0.100?  You should be able to ping it.   But even if you can, ultimately you will have problems because you can't have two default gateways.  Also, your static routes should point to the gateway IP address and not the interface.

Comment: You're right, I had wrong static routes. Connection now works without any problem, but I can't get working two DNS servers together. If router's DNS is on first line in `/etc/resolv.conf` then I'm able to access all domains which are covered by this DNS. If DNS 10.240.93.5 is on the first line in previous mentioned file, then I'm able to access all domains which are covered only by this DNS. How can I connect those two (or three if I can also add 10.240.93.6) servers to answer on my requests even if one domain is not resoloved by one of the DNS servers?

Comment: @Ron any suggestion on previous comment? If you have any comment on that, please open new answer, so I can thick it as correct after that. Thank you!

Comment: There are many linux users here who can answer this better than I can.  You might consider asking this as a separate question.